# Automated Gannt Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to create an automated gannt chart in Excel, where if I add a date at the top then a red line is drawn on the right hand side, all the way down. How can I do this with VBA?
[image: sheet]

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need e VBA to implement such formatting. Follow the steps shown on the below example:

1. Select the range of cells, where if a date added at the top then a red line is drawn on the right hand side, all the way down:

[image: select cells]

2. Click Menu - Conditional Formatting - New Rule:

[image: new rule]

3. In opened window choose "Use a formula ...", enter formula e. g. `=N$1<>""` and click <kbd>Format</kbd>:

[image: enter formula]

4. In opened window, click on Border tab, set the necessary format, e. g. red border to the right, click <kbd>OK</kbd>, and again click <kbd>OK</kbd> in previous window:

[image: set red border]

5. Now selected column contains the necessary formatting and works, all that is left to do is to apply the format to the entire chart range. Click Menu - Conditional Formatting - Manage Rules:

[image: Manage Rules]

6. In opened window change the target range the formatting is applied to, click <kbd>OK</kbd>:

[image: change applied range]

7. Check how it works. Enter any value at the top cell, then that column border highlights red.

[image: check]

The only assumption for the method is that the formula will trigger if the cell is just not empty, it's necessary to create more complex formula to make a check if the value is exactly a date.

Comment: Upvoted for the effort... but IMO the question was off-topic in the first place.

Comment: This is great thanks!